# Malicious *URLs*?

Tags: exploit, attack-vector

Everyone says not to click on "malicious URLs".  Are there any attacks where the URL itself, rather than the resource accessed by the URL, is the attack vector?

Comment: [Yep!](https://jon.oberheide.org/moab/MOAB-30-01-2007.html) (The same thing happened more recently with the custom protocol handler dialog in Safari on Mac OS X, but I haven’t been able to find it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually this is very timely as there's a relatively new attack where the data passed in the URL is the attack vector.

[Reflected File Download](http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2014/10/reflected-file-download-the-white-paper.html) abuses non-malicious servers by passing them malicious data and then having it reflected back to users, so it appears to the user to have come from a "trusted" source.

Comment: just read the paper; first impression: "will this ever end?"

Comment: Is RFD attacks still reproducible on OSX Chome? I just tried and can't get it to work.